# in message simple form fulfillment accelerator with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create some simple data input over a plain chat message using `regex` and `capturing groups` . The idea is to let the user `write a lot of things` then use the scape `#` and then `name: anything; description: anything 2; complement : anything 3...`

Some requirements and characteristics of this puzzle:

1. I know the name of the fields
2. The fields are in any order
3. Field complement is optional
4. We can't repeat the fields in the same message (too complex I think so is a nice to have, I can process it in the server)
5. I need to be able to capture field and value for each field
6. The regex sintaxe must be executed on the client because I need highlight while the user is typing
7. It is not obligatory to add a `#` to submit

For the first (user write what he/she needs until the scape `#`) I wrote

First part, free text (FT): `([,\w\s():\.\$]*)`

For the second part, I thought that I should have the following: `((#(obligatory pair)+);?)*)`   being the last `*` to ensure that the whole `#` sequence is not obligatory but once he/she adds the `#`, the pattern must be followed.

So I ended up with the following [(here in regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/T3h9g8/4):

```
([,\w\s():\.\$]*)(?:(?:#(?:(?:\s*(name|description|complement)):([,\w\s():\.\$]+))+;?)*)
```

and used in the following text (in the link above as well)

```
This is is the free text that the user is writing. Now with the scape # name: free text to write; description: another free text and then ; complement : yet another one
```

Now of course this won't work but not only because of the problem I knew that I would have which is I can't control if `"name"` was or wasn't used. 
The problem is that with `-g`, only the firs field `name` is captured, and with `+g` the `description` and `complement` are clearly not part of the match in the pattern, as I can create another filed called `completelyWrong` and it will appear in my captures.

I am pretty sure that as I am new in the regex world this is a precarious solution. Any help is very welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?:^[^#]*|([a-z]+)\s*:\s*([^;]*))
```

It matches user text with the first match, and matches all the fields with their names in group 1 and content in group 2.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/T3h9g8/5)

Comment: Any another elegant way to prevent \1 (which is in this case [a-z]) from repeating?